# JQUERY, getting two BINDs/Clicks to play nice together?

Tags: jquery, click, onclick, bind

I have the following line of code:

```
<li id="1" class=" ">
<a href="">Parking Lot</a>
<span id="1" class="list-edit">edit</span>
</li>
```

I then have two binds:

```
$("#lists li").click(function(){.......

$(".list-edit").click(function(){.........
```

The problem I'm having is I need the LI to contain the EDIT span because of CSS styling reasons, I have a big blue background. But this is preventing me from binding the EDIT btn. Is there a way to get these two to play nice?

Thxs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`event.stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to prevent the click handler attached to the parent LI from firing when the edit span is clicked (if that's what you mean):

```
$(".list-edit").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: Turns out this doesn't work... It's still catching both of the binds.

Comment: @nobosh - are you passing the event object through the callback? i.e. `$(".list-edit").click(function(e){`